# java jndi ldap connection timeout

Tags: java, ldap, timeout, jndi

I want to control the connection timeout by setting `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout` property. It works well for values under 1000 ms, but if I set values bigger then 1000, the timeout doesn't increase (it remains at 1000).

Here is the code I tried to test it with (the server is down):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

try
{
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin,ou=system");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "10000");

    InitialLdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

} catch (NamingException e)
{
    System.out.println("Failed because " + e.getRootCause()
            .getMessage() + ". Timeout: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start)) + " ms.");
}
```

What might cause this?

Comment: Seems it had something to do with the fact that I set the PROVIDER_URL to localhost. I did some debugging in the java.net classes and discovered that the timeout was passed correctly to a native method. Changing the provider to something other then localhost makes it wait for the specified amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the target host responds to the connect request with an error code, the connection fails as soon as the error code is received. It appears that the target host was up and the target LDAP service wasn't listening at port 10389. So the target host responded to the incoming connect request with an RST, so an exception was thrown immediately at the client. This is expected behaviour. You surely don't want to *delay* receiving the error? The connect timeout is for the case when the target host is temporarily unreachable or the target service is *really* busy.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?35809) about this topic. Seems this property doesn't really work this way. Maybe [this follow-up thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?56533) can help to.

Comment: Those springsource forums posts are lost, like tears in the rain.